# Deploy -> update -> deploy routine in cdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

For example I have these two lambda in `CdkStBaseStack`

It can be deployed by `cdk deploy` at first.

Hoever later,when I updated the code in `resizer-sam/resizer`.

So, I want to deploy new version of `ResizerLambda`

Is there any method to deploy the update version?

Or I need to prepare some tools besides cdk?

```
const resizerLambda = new lambda.DockerImageFunction(this, "ResizerLambda", {
  code: lambda.DockerImageCode.fromImageAsset("resizer-sam/resizer"),
  functionName: `cdk-st-${targetEnv}-resizer-lm`
});
const mybaseLambda = new lambda.DockerImageFunction(this, "MyBaseLambda", {
  code: lambda.DockerImageCode.fromImageAsset("mybase-sam/mybase"),
  functionName: `cdk-st-${targetEnv}-mybase-lm`
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understood the question correctly, doing a simple `cdk deploy` would bundle the new code and update your function accordingly.

Comment: Thank you I wrongly thought about concept of cdk.... now it works well for me.